# Cannot convert generic

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to call the method `BinaryFileDeSerialize` from the manager class, but I get a conversion problem.

```
public List<T> BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(string filePath) where T : class
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException("The file" + " was not found. ", filePath);
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();

        while (fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length)
            list.Add((T)b.Deserialize(fileStream));
    }

    return list;
}
```

`Manager` class:

```
private List<T> m_list;

public ListManager()
{
    m_list = new List<T>();
} 

public List<T> Open(string filename)
{
    BinSerializerUtility binSerial = new BinSerializerUtility();
    return binSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<List<T>>(filename); //<-- Errror

}
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List>'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

**UPDATE:**

I tried `return binSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(filename);`
but I got error:

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter
>   'T' in the generic type or method
>   'Assign_1.BinSerializerUtility.BinaryFileDeSerialize(string)

Comment: Pretty sure return binSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<List<T>>(filename); should just be return binSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(filename); Since you are trying to convert a List of List to a single List.

Comment: the error just from first glance appears to be in your return type you are returning a List vs something of type `binSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize` what is the type of binSerial try the following 
`return binSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(filename);`

Comment: Add "where T : class" to the end of the Open function.

Comment: What type are you trying to use in the `T` generic type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your Open() method to have generic constraint for reference type.

**Updated:**

```
public List<T> Open<T>(string filename) where T: class
        {
            BinSerializerUtility binSerial = new BinSerializerUtility();
            return binSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(filename); 

        }
```

Comment: Still an error, the List<T> needs to be replaced with just T in the return call.

Comment: Error:
**Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declaration**

Comment: Udpated the method. Thanks @John.P

Comment: @FelipeOriani Method are allowed to have constraints if they are declared as generic.

Answer (score 0):

**First error** appear because the `T` is `List<T>` and at result you get a `List<List<T>>`, to solve this you have to pass just `T`.

**Second error** is because the method `BinaryFileDeSerialize` have `T : class` which means that `T` is reference type.

```
public class ListManager<T> where T : class //  T is reference type
{
    private List<T> m_list;

    public ListManager()
    {
        m_list = new List<T>();
    }

    public List<T> Open(string filename)
    {
        BinSerializerUtility binSerial = new BinSerializerUtility();
        return binSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(filename); // just T
    }
}
```